How to hide server api call request from browser network Fetch/XHR requests list?
I have Nuxt 3 project with two pages and one server API:
Configuration file: nuxt.config.ts
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    routeRules: {
        '/api/**': {
            cache: { maxAge: 60 },
            swr: true
        }
    }
})

Page 1: hello.vue
<template>
    <div>
        <h2>Page Hello</h2>
        <NuxtLink to="/world">Go to World!</NuxtLink>
        <div>
            <pre>
                {{ advantages }}
            </pre>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script setup>
    const { data: advantages, error } = await useFetch('/api/advantages', {
        server: true
    })
</script>

Page 2: world.vue
<template>
    <div>
        <h2>Page World</h2>
        <NuxtLink to="/hello">Go to World!</NuxtLink>
        <div>
            <pre>
                {{ advantages }}
            </pre>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script setup>
    const { data: advantages, error } = await useFetch('/api/advantages', {
        server: true
    })
</script>

Server API: server/api/advantages.ts
export default defineEventHandler(async event => {
    try {
        const res = await fetch('https://example.com/api/advantages')
        const data = await res.json()
        return data
    } catch (error: any) {
        throw createError({
            statusCode: 500,
            message: `Error fetching advantages: ${error.message}`
        })
    }
})

When the site first loads, all requests are made on the server side. As you can see, I have configured caching of API requests in the framework configuration file. While the cache is in effect, the framework does not actually send a repeated request to the external API service.
Problem
I need to hide requests sent to the project server/api folder when moving from page to page (e.g., from /hello to /world) after loading the site from the browser Fetch/XHR requests list for site security


What kind of "site security"? You're already wrapping a request to example.com, likely to not expose it

I just don’t want the user to see requests for the server/api folder and all requests executed on the server side. @EstusFlask

This requirement needs to be justified because this may restrict your app design without a good reason. You can use rate limiting, cors and other ways to misuse your api if necessary. Any way, check https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/components#server-components

In my case api requests are friendly with SEO? @EstusFlask

Supposedly yes, the content you need to provide to search engine is supposed available as static html on initial load, can be confirmed by checking page response

Is it possible to solve the problem about hiding api requests in client side simply by using Pinia as storage by saving first server side api request response to store? @EstusFlask

Yes, it's possible, I guess. You'll likely expose /api/advantages' endpoint any way in source code this way. It's unknown what's your motivation for hiding it, "security through obscurity" isn't security. As said, this needs to be justified, otherwise you may end up jumping through hoops for no good reason. I'd go with SSR-only chunks for sensitive parts, e.g. if I don't want content to be easily parsed

This is the way nuxt (and other frameworks) works in Universal rendering mode:
The first page visit is rendered in the server side, once the client-side is loaded all subsequent navigation is done on the client-side only. So to render the next page nuxt makes all the api calls in the browser.
More details here.
However there is a feature that might do what you are looking for as it attemps to generate pure static html/css :
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  features: {
    noScripts: true
  }
})

More info here: docs
